# Why Doctrine MongoDB ODM findBy and execute returns different classes?

Tags: mongodb, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine-odm, doctrine-query

sBased on Doctrine documentation `$qb->getQuery()->execute();` will return a cursor for you to iterator over the results but  `$qb->find($criteria);` returns the actual found Documents.

I am using `symfony2` `MongoDBbundle` and I would like to avoid iterating over the result set in `Repository` classes.

```
// Returns Product Document 
$entity = $this->get('doctrine_mongodb')
               ->getRepository("MyBundle:Product")
               ->findOneBy(array('title' => 'somthing'));


// Returns Cursor
$entity = $this->get('doctrine_mongodb')
               ->getRepository("MyBundle:Product")
               ->customFunctionWithcreateQueryBuilder(array('title' => 'somthing'));
```

How can I make `cutomFunctionWithcreateQueryBuilder()` returns the same class/result as `findOneBy`?

Also How can I make `execute()` returns all embedded documents?

**EDIT**

Content Of cutomFunctionWithcreateQueryBuilder:

```
class ProductRepository extends DocumentRepository {

public function customFunctionWithcreateQueryBuilder($param, $hydrate = true) {

        $query = $this->createQueryBuilder()
                ->select()
                ->hydrate($hydrate);

        if (isset($param['unique_id'])) {
            $query->field('id')->equals($param['unique_id']);
        }

        return $query->getQuery()->execute();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `getSingleResult()` if you want only one result and set [eagerCursor](http://doctrine-mongodb-odm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/eager-cursors.html) to true to get all data at once. In example:

```
    [...] 

    if (isset($param['unique_id'])) {
        $query->field('id')->equals($param['unique_id']);
    }

    return $query->eagerCursor(true)->getQuery()->getSingleResult();


    [...]
```